# Azure API Management Import API always says: API with specified name already exists

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to import an API I have into Azure API Management using swagger, should be fairly simple but I always get the same error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: API with specified name
>   already exists

I do not have ANYTHING setup in Azure API management yet, very frustrating.

**UPDATE**

I am using Swashbuckle (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to add Swagger to my WebAPI project.

It is generating Swagger 2.0 docs.

Here is the info element of the Swagger Doc:

```
swagger: "2.0",
info: {
version: "v3",
title: "ShopZioAPIv3"
},
```

It does not matter what I change that to, I still always get:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: API with specified name
>   already exists

Comment: Is your Swagger a v1.2 or 2.0?  Is it possible to share your swagger doc, or at least the info object of the swagger doc?

Comment: Swagger 2.0, I added clarification above

Comment: I have an API that I recently installed Swashbuckle into, I've been meaning to try importing it.  Let me try it and see if I can repro your issue.

Comment: thanks, I have tried just about everything I can think of, added in SwaggerAttributes everywhere, XML Comment generation so my Swagger doc is looking really, really good but still not working on the import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error message appears when you don't specify a unique API prefix.

I realize that you said that you don't have anything already already setup in the API however, if you could try putting some unique value in this field:

[image: API Prefix field]

An API Management service instance is designed to host multiple APIs, so the prefix is used to differentiate between the APIs by using the first part of the path.

The subdomain part of the URL is used to identify the service.  e.g.

```
http://{servicename}.azure-api.net{/api-prefix}/path/segment?param=value
```

---

### Update

Based on the provided Swagger, the problem comes from multiple operation objects with the same OperationId.  This is invalid swagger.

Usually Swashbuckle will fail before generating operations with duplicate Ids.  There is a ResolveConflictingActions method that allow you to put your own code to deal with these cases.  It seems like in this case the resolution code is not doing the right thing.

Comment: I have tried so many different values it is ridiculous, was just trying random anything just to see if I could get it to work.  Theoretically if I do not have ANY api's off this subdomain yet anything should be unique.

Comment: @Slee  So, just to confirm, you have tried putting different values in the "Web API URL Suffix" text box that appears in the publisher portal UI when trying to import an API.  I'm not talking about changing values in the Swagger itself.

Comment: @Slee I realize this is not much of consolation, but you are not crazy.  I'm getting the same behaviour with your swagger.

Comment: I might start killing off methods just to see which one may be causing a problem

Comment: @Slee  So the problem is that there are multiple operations with the same operationId.  `/api/carts` and `/api/carts/{manufactureId}` both have the OperationId Cart_Get.  I need to check the Swagger spec to see if that is supposed to be a unique name,

Comment: I just imported your Swagger into my account on swaggerhub,com and it tells me that the duplicate operationids are not allowed by the swagger spec.  So I guess it is Swashbuckle that has the issue.Oh, and we could do a better job of reporting the error in APIM.

Comment: @Slee Have you written your own ResolveConflctingActions method?

Comment: Thanks Darrel, I have not written my own ResolveConflictingActions method yet, just found out about Swagger day ago so I am learning as I go here.  Weird part is this imported and will publish at SwaggerHub.com for me without issue - I did not know about SwaggerHub either, so thanks for that, at least now I know what the issue is

Comment: @Slee  Did you have the default ResolveConflictingActions enabled?  The one that picks the first match?  If I don't have that then rendering the swagger fails and if I do then I don't get dup ids.

Comment: it is commented out in my SwaggerConfig.cs, weird that I am not getting failing for dup id's and you are, FYI I am using Swashbuckle 5.2.2. Either way I used the SwaggerOperation attribute to fix the OperationID conflicts the APIM import was detecting

Comment: @DarrelMiller - Can we avoid to enter a operationId value? I am facing an issue where my endpoint is shared by both the default and v1 endpoint - I have made a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675490/what-is-the-way-to-handle-swagger-operationid-value-for-default-and-versioned-en

Answer (score 5):

I my case the title `{"info":{"title": "API-NAME",...` in the Swagger file did not match the name of the selected API (because we had created several test APIs).

Simply changing the string value fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case I was exporting from one API and importing into another (trying to move operations around). I tried the Swagger and WADL exports that API Mgmnt itself provided and they were erroring out. I ended up using the WADL and when I changed the title attribute of the doc tag to match the destination API it worked. Seems like an implementation bug - why doesn't it ignore the API name property if I'm importing into an existing API?

Comment: This has worked for me, too. 1 Up vote from me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Azure API Management error, "API with specified name already exists," can be misleading, and in this case, it is inaccurate.

As discussed in [Darrel Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400969/430202), invalid Swagger can cause this issue.  Although multiple operation objects with the same OperationId is invalid in Swagger 2.0, I think the core issue you are having is that [Azure API Management does not yet support Swagger 2.0](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-import-api/#comment-1600971564) (as of Dec 1, 2015).

Swashbuckle 5+ generates only Swagger 2.0 so some,if not all, definitions generated with it will fail with this error -- even well-formed Swagger definitions validated by http://editor.swagger.io, which also seems to only support Swagger 2.0.

Swashbuckle 4.2 supports generating Swagger 1.2 definitions.

Also, I was able to take my Swagger 2.0 definition (generated by Swashbuckle 5), and convert it to Swagger 1.2 using [Restlet Studio](http://studio.restlet.com/).

Comment: Swagger 2.0 is supported now.